# Safari search suggestions reopen after search is completed

Tags: safari, search

This is a really annoying bug I've been experiencing since a while.

1. Enter a query in the search bar in Safari.
2. A drop-down list of suggestions appear.
3. I hit enter to perform the search, the respective Google page is loaded.
4. The drop-down **suggestions are opened a second time**. (The search field is still highlighted, which is the case for all four possible search engines.)

It **only** occurs if

1. Safari is in full screen mode and
2. Google or DuckDuckGo are set as search engine.

I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and Safari 10.0.1 but as I said, the problem has been here a while (at least a year).

Can anybody reproduce this? Is there a possible fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT I thought I figured it out, but I tested with DuckDuckGo and it does not redirect you to a different domain. Yet the problem still occurs on that site. So the mystery continues. The first workaround might still work for you if you are using Google. The second workaround should work in any case.

I am able to reproduce this bug and have a few workarounds.

The reason this bug hasn't been fixed yet might be that it not always occurs when in full screen, you have to be in a different country than the U.S.A. too. It seems that the redirection to a different country domain causes this behaviour. I assume all the Safari developers reside in the U.S.A., so they never experience this behaviour.

Now for the workarounds:

**Option 1**

If you are using Google, visit [google.com/ncr](http://google.com/ncr). This sets a cookie preventing redirection to a local Google site. The bug will disappear until you clear your cookies. There should be similar options for other search engines.

If you want it to disappear permanently or if you want to keep using your local site, we have:

**Option 2**

Add the [AnySearch](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.matt-swain.anysearch-6M853ET88Q) extension to Safari and configure it to use your search engine of choice. The bug does not seem to occur when using this extension.

I filed a detailed bug report with Apple btw. Hope it gets fixed in the near future.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for your help in pinpointing the issue! The problem with the localization really explains why the responses I got on other websites were so mixed. For the time being, I'll use AnySearch as that really seems to be a reliable fix.