# Safari search bar doesn't lose focus on Enter

Tags: safari, macos

When I'm searching something using Safari's search bar, the search bar doesn't lose the focus when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so the suggestions shows up again.

Has someone else had this problem? Is there a way to fix this?
I'm using Safari 10 on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Which version of macOS Sierra?

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: I get stuck too sometimes in the address/search bar, and to loose focus and get it back on the web page, for scrolling with the keyboard for example, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, eventually several times. I am a new Mac user, running macOS High Sierra 10.13 and Safari 11 at the moment, so I'm not sure if it's just me that have not learnt the OS and all keyboard shortcuts yet, but that the fix or solution for me anyway.

Comment: Is safari the only browser or application where the "Enter" key isnt performing as normal? Also how do the keypress feel. Is it a normal key travel? If not perhaps you'll need to clean it with a can of compressed air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of the small unnoticed things that I accepted to live with. [This issue has been going on for years](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262115/safari-search-suggestions-reopen-after-search-is-completed).

I tried to bypass the issue by installing an extension [from the safari extension gallery](https://safari-extensions.apple.com) that performs searches and those work for some time and the issues ultimately comes back again.

**Edit:**

As of Safari 13.0.1 in macOS Catalina, I don't experience that bug anymore, seems good so far